# How can i know if native visual voicemail on Android M is activated or not?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, voicemail

As we know from Android M, Google provides a native VVM(Visual Voicemail) for users in a tag of System's Phone. And VVM service is activated by default. Of course, user can choose to deactivate VVM.

But how can i know if the native VVM is activated or not programmatically?
[tag of VVM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtoFq.jpg)

[VVM setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtoFq.jpg)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtoFq.jpg): [image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtoFq.jpg): [image]